# Is providing a user with a 'change view' option when completing a long form a good user experience?

Tags: forms, design-patterns

For context, I am designing a new form that a user is required to complete in a modal window. I have two options designed: a long scrollable form, and the same form broken into sections displayed using a stepper/wizard pattern. The form is part of the users day to day workflow and will be completed multiple times a day across multiple internal applications.

I have done some initial research with a small set of users to demo prototypes of the two options above and they are split 50/50, so I am now considering providing both options as a user preference, which would set the default loaded view with the choice to change, similar to a list/grid view selection on an ecommerce site.

Is there any research on these options? Are there any concerns with providing the user an option to choose how this is displayed to them?

Comment: "Providing control to users" is one of the principles in all existing UX heuristics, so you should be fine on that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is tons of research and case studies out there suggesting multi-steps forms are best. e.g:
https://medium.com/@jenningscreate/case-study-stans-ac-multi-step-form-25ee54cfb5aa
https://www.business2community.com/online-marketing/testing-2-step-vs-1-step-conversion-forms-022833
https://conversionfanatics.com/multi-step-or-single-step-forms/

But existing research and best practices won't always apply to your users and your user cases. If your users have to complete this form multiple times each day, then your UX goals aren't focused on conversion, your users have to complete the task. The only concern with giving users this option would just be the effort of building and maintaining both. That effort would probably pale in comparison to the user time you're saving them by allowing them to choose.